# HERE Maps API for JavaScript Testing Bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, here-api, jsdom

**Update:** I'm still getting the same problem as below, but now the following error is posted to the console by JSDom:

```
Error: Uncaught [SyntaxError: ]
    at reportException (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:58:24)
    at processJavaScript (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:130:7)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._eval (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:65:7)
    at e (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js:30:22)
    at Object.check (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:97:11)
    at /Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:116:12
    at wrappedEnqueued (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js:234:16)
    at Request.request [as _callback] (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js:184:9)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:934:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) SyntaxError
    at XMLHttpRequest.open (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:451:15)
    at http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:51:86
    at http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:51:383
    at http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:290:26
    at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:44:17)
    at processJavaScript (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:128:10)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._eval (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:65:7)
    at e (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js:30:22)
    at Object.check (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:97:11)
    at /Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:116:12
    at wrappedEnqueued (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js:234:16)
    at Request.request [as _callback] (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js:184:9)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:934:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

---

I'm trying to get the HERE Maps JavaScript API to work correctly within a test written using Mocha.

```
it("should generate a map when the component gets rendered", function generateMapTest(done) {
    this.timeout(0);
    const scriptMap = getScriptMap();
    const scriptNames = Object.keys(scriptMap);
    const finalScriptToLoad = last(scriptNames);

    getScript(finalScriptToLoad).onLoad((err: any, res?: any) => {
        global.H = window.H;

        const platform = new H.service.Platform({
            app_id: 'app_id',
            app_code: 'app_code',
        });

        console.log(window.H);
        done(err);
    });
});
```

To explain the above - the scriptMap variable is used to store an object containing the URLs of each HERE Maps script that is to be loaded. Each script is loaded sequentially by using JavaScript to append  tags to the DOM (using jsdom). When each script loads, every callback in an array of callbacks is called, passing the usual error and response objects. Callbacks are added to this array using the onLoad method shown below.

When the final script is finished loading from the HERE servers, I attach the H object to the global variable in Mocha and attempt to create a Platform service. This results in the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'mapsjs-core' of undefined
    at Hi (http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:287:626)
    at Ji (http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:288:350)
    at V.Es (eval at <anonymous> (http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:47:404), <anonymous>:13:188)
    at new V (eval at <anonymous> (http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:47:404), <anonymous>:12:257)
    at Object.getPlatform (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/src/utils/get-platform.js:9:16)
    at /Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/src/HEREMap.js:34:50
    at /Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/src/utils/cache.js:52:104
    at arrayEach (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:522:11)
    at Function.forEach (/Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9011:14)
    at /Users/joshua/Dropbox/Projects/Web Development/NPM Modules/react-here-maps/src/utils/cache.js:52:30
```

I am struggling to debug the minified versions of the code provided, so if I could have some assistance tracking down the source of this bug I would appreciate it. It's probably worth stating that all this is in the context of building a HERE Maps React component, the source code can be found here: https://github.com/josh-es/react-here-maps.

~^~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to isolate the problem to the JSDom implementation of the XMLHttpRequest API. Replacing it with the 'xmlhttprequest' npm package fixed the problem. Install it by running:

```
npm install --save-dev xmlhttprequest
```

And then fix the above issue:

```
import { XMLHttpRequest } from "xmlhttprequest";

global.window.XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
```